# Can a Temporally Shunted character use any remaining actions for its turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reactions, action-economy

As an example of the sort of action I'm talking about, at 7th level, when an [Arcane Archer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ArcaneArcher)  misses an attack, they can spend a bonus action to redirect their arrow with Curving Arrow:

> [...] you can use a bonus action to reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target.

The reaction for [Temporal Shunt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/temporal-shunt) is taken:

> when a creature you can see makes an attack roll or starts to cast a spell

The target, if it fails the saving throw is will,

> vanish, being thrown to another point in time and causing the attack to miss or the spell to be wasted.

Now, vanish is not a game term as far as I am aware. This is not necessarily a problem, as the terminology in other 'banishment' type spells doesn't always use game terms, for instance Maze:

> You banish a creature that you can see within range into a labyrinthine demiplane. The target remains there for the duration or until it escapes the maze.

But no other similar effect can interrupt a turn. [Maze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/maze) even shows how the target can use actions on its turn to try and end the effect early. [Banishing Smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishing-smite) incapacitates the target, preventing a similar issue if they use it during another creature's turn.

Is the Arcane Archer, or any other character with a similarly available action able to use use that action before or during the effects of Temporal Shunt?

A different example would be Temporal Shunt used on a Longtooth Shifter attacking with their racial bonus action before having taken other actions, or a character with the sentinel feat using its reaction to respond to an attack on their turn.

What happens to the rest of the character's turn and/or actions and movement?

Comment: Related: "[What can a creature affected by a Warlock's 'Hurl Through Hell' do?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120297)"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### For the target, there is no time between failing the save and the beginning of their next turn.

*Temporal shunt* says:

> You target the triggering creature, which must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or vanish, being *thrown to another point in time* and causing the attack to miss or the spell to be wasted. At the start of its next turn, the target reappears where it was or in the closest unoccupied space. *The target doesn’t remember you casting the spell or being affected by it.*

This tells us what the timeline is for the target: from their perspective, the start of their next turn occurs immediately after they fail the saving throw. They vanish from the present and reappear in what we presently call the future. They are not stored anywhere, they do not go to an extradimensional space as with the spell *banishment*. They blink and six seconds have passed.

They cannot do anything else because for them, there is no time between failing the save and the beginning of their next turn.

Comment: Ahhh that reading is clearer and causes fewer/different issues. I had assumed "*another point in time*" was vague enough that it wasn't for certain they go straight to their next turn, and do not pass go. I assumed (perhaps wrongly) the final clause was *needed* to explain that they didn't remember when in time they went.